# Got white blank page after copying the functions.php to child theme

Tags: functions, child-theme

I got white blank page after copying the functions.php to my child theme.

How can I change "like_escape"? What file can I find that?

And I see this notice:

```
Notice: like_escape is deprecated since version 4.0! Use wpdb::esc_like() instead. in /home7/homecre1/public_html/betasite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3201
```

and that notice display here

http://goo.gl/zgWVMQ

I don't use any plugin for my search engine

Here's the functions.php

```
<?php
/**
* AccessPress Ray functions and definitions
*
* @package AccessPress Ray
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'accesspress_ray_setup' ) ) :
/**
* Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
*
* Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
* runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
* as indicating support for post thumbnails.
*/
function accesspress_ray_setup() {
/**
 * Set the content width based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 */
global $content_width;
/**
 * Global content width.
 */
 if (!isset($content_width))
    $content_width = 750; /* pixels */

/*
 * Make theme available for translation.
 * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
 * If you're building a theme based on AccessPress Ray, use a find and replace
 * to change 'accesspress_ray' to the name of your theme in all the template files
 */
load_theme_textdomain( 'accesspress_ray', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

/**
 * Add callback for custom TinyMCE editor stylesheets. (editor-style.css)
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style
 */
add_editor_style(); 

 // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
 add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
 add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'gallery', 'caption' ) );
 /*
 * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
 *
 * @link   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
 */
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

 add_image_size( 'event-thumbnail', 135, 100, true); //Latest News Events Small Image
 add_image_size( 'featured-thumbnail', 350, 245, true); //Featured Image
 add_image_size( 'portfolio-thumbnail', 400, 450, true); //Portfolio Image      

 // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
 register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'accesspress_ray' ),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'accesspress_ray' ),
 ) );

 // Setup the WordPress core custom background feature.
 add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters(  'accesspress_ray_custom_background_args', array(
    'default-color' => 'ffffff',
    'default-image' => '',
) ) );

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
 }
 endif; // accesspress_ray_setup
 add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'accesspress_ray_setup' );

/**
* Implement the Theme Option feature.
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/accesspressray-custom-header.php';

/**
* Implement the Theme Option feature.
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/admin-panel/accesspressray-theme-options.php';

/**
* Custom template tags for this theme.
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/accesspressray-template-tags.php';

/**
* Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
*/
 require get_template_directory() . '/inc/accesspressray-custom-functions.php';

/**
* Implement the custom metabox feature
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/accesspressray-custom-metabox.php';

/**
* Load Jetpack compatibility file.
*/
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
```

Comment: Try to activate your `WP_DEBUG` and edit your question with the error you will see on your screen.

Comment: @Bordoni question is now updated

Comment: like_escape "is still available as a deprecated function, so it still works in any existing plugins that rely on it." AFAIK, it should not cause a white page.  https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/06/20/like_escape-is-deprecated-in-wordpress-4-0/

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum but I want to copy the functions.php in my child theme and when I did that, my website display a full blank white page

Comment: That said, if it is the cause of the problem, it's in one of your required files. Try to comment them out one at a time and see if you can narrow it down to the file containing the offending code.

Comment: You copied functions.php from your child theme to where?

Comment: I mean, I copy the functions.php from the original theme to child theme

Comment: Did the answer below solve the issue?

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum not yet. I don't know what file should I modify just to solve that notice

Comment: This question regards the white page issue. Is that solved? If you would like to address the notice specifically, research the notice and, if needed, post a question regarding the notice.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have duplicate copies of your functions.php file. After copying it to your child theme, the original functions.php (the one in the parent theme) should be left blank so functions are not duplicated. This is probably why the notice occurs twice on your website, but the notice is likely unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to copy the parent theme functions into your child theme at all. WordPress will load the functions.php from the Parent theme. Your child theme functions will be loaded AFTER that. Simply keep your parent theme untouched, and keep your child theme functions.php file empty and it'll be fine. Then you can add additional customizations in your child theme and they will load as well.

See here (search for "child theme" in the page) for more details:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/